# Angular app javascript hanging in some Firefox browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, bower, masonry

For some reason my angular app is crashing on some firefox browsers... Some users reported in on mobile and pc though I wasn't able to get the error using a pc.
The error is about some javascript hanging. I get the file and the line each time but it's often different. For exemple jquery:2 or it's in eventEmitter or outlayer. I have all these dependencies because I use angular-masonry
Here's my `bower.json`

```
       {
      "name": "yosl",
      "version": "0.0.0",
      "dependencies": {
        "jquery": "~2.1.4",
        "jquery-bridget": "~1.1.0",
        "angular": "1.3.15",
        "outlayer": "~1.4.2",
        "masonry": "3.3.2",
        "imagesloaded": "3.1.7",
        "angular-masonry": "~0.13.0",
        "get-size": "~1.2.2",
        "get-style-property": "~1.0.4",
        "eventie": "~1.0.6",
        "doc-ready": "~1.0.4",
        "eventEmitter": "~4.3.0",
        "matches-selector": "~1.0.3",
        "fizzy-ui-utils": "~1.0.1",
        "angular-resource": "1.3.15",
        "angular-ui-router": "0.2.13",
        "json3": "~3.3.1",
        "es5-shim": "~3.1.0",
        "bootstrap": "~3.1.1",
        "angular-cookies": "1.3.15",
        "angular-sanitize": "1.3.15",
        "angular-animate": "1.3.15",
        "angular-touch": "1.3.15",
        "semantic-ui-flag": "1.11.6",
        "angular-motion": "~0.3.4",
        "angular-strap": "~2.2.1",
        "bootstrap-switch": "*",
        "bootstrap-tagsinput": "~0.4.2",
        "angular-environment": "~1.0.3",
        "ng-dialog": "~0.5.5",
        "font-awesome": "~4.4.0"
      },
      "overrides": {
        "outlayer": {
          "main": [
            "item.js",
            "outlayer.js"
          ]
        }
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "angular-mocks": "1.3.15",
        "angular-scenario": "1.3.15"
      },
      "appPath": "app",
      "resolutions": {
        "angular": "^1.2.21"
      }
    }
```

Comment: It's pretty hard to give you an answer without seeing any of your code...

Comment: I know. But I don't know which portion of the code to show you as the error always point to a different line of external librairies... It looks like some dependency issues to me but idk